# Error in running the volumes in docker toolbox

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, docker-toolbox

This is the docker-compose file I have already set the folder to share by Virtual Box VM but it is still not working.

```
version: '3'
    services:
      postgres:
        image: 'postgres:latest'
        deploy:  
          restart_policy:  
            condition: on-failure  
            window: 15m  
      redis:
        image: 'redis:latest'
      nginx:
        restart: always
        build:
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
          context: ./nginx
        ports:
          - '3050:80'  
      api:
        build:
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
          context: ./server
        volumes:
          - /usr/src/app/node_modules
          - ./server:/usr/src/app
        environment:
          - REDIS_HOST=redis
          - REDIS_PORT=6379
          - PGUSER=postgres
          - PGHOST=postgres
          - PGDATABASE=postgres
          - PGPASSWORD=postgres_password
          - PGPORT=5432
      client:
        build:
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
          context: ./client
        volumes:
          - /usr/src/app/node_modules
          - ./client:/usr/src/app
      worker:
        build:
          dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
          context: ./worker
        volumes:
          - /usr/src/app/node_modules
          - ./worker:/usr/src/app
```

I am running it on Windows 7 sp1. Whenever I run `docker-compose up` - I get an error:

```
api_1       | npm ERR! code ENOENT
api_1       | npm ERR! syscall open
api_1       | npm ERR! path /usr/src/app/package.json
api_1       | npm ERR! errno -2
api_1       | npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/usr/src/
app/package.json'
api_1       | npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a fi
le.
api_1       | npm ERR! enoent
api_1       |
api_1       | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
api_1       | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-05-28T04_06_56_121Z-debug.log
complex_api_1 exited with code 254
```

Thanks in advance, please help.
I am trying to run a Fibonacci project from the Udemy course of Docker and Kubernetes complete guide.
[image]

[image]

Each service has its own package.json and other files.

Server Docker File :

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .


CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Worker Docker File :

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Client Docker File :

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . .


CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: You should probably delete all of those `volumes:` blocks.  That will let Docker run the code that's built into the image, instead of overwriting it.  That "overwrite" behavior is leading to the "no such file or directory" error: whatever content is in your host directory isn't compatible with the layout in the image and you're hiding everything there.

Comment: But if i Delete volume blocks then the project is not running properly as it is a dynamic project .

Comment: Reading better, we are following the same udemy course  concurrently and we are at the same lesson (near 130)  Try with the solution that I posted. It should works

Comment: I tried but it is still not working i even shared the folder and added its path in oracle VM box but still it gives out the same error.

Comment: Share your console terminal also

Comment: Put It on c/Users/YOURUSER, not in Users only!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data between containers

```
services:
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - datavolume:/usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
  worker:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./worker
    volumes:
      - datavolume:/usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ./worker:/usr/src/app 
volumes:
  datavolume: {}
```

Since it looks like your dev, I would suggest mount your workspace folder into container

```
services:
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - ./node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
  worker:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./worker
    volumes:
      - ./node_modules:/usr/src/app/node_modules
      - ./worker:/usr/src/app
```

And better way is treating every service a standalone project. Each of them should own their self package.json and node_modules.

```
services:
  client:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
  worker:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./worker
    volumes:
      - ./worker:/usr/src/app
```

In my opinion, it doesn't make sense to use same libraries in different project which in different purpose.

Comment: I tried it but it is not working still the error persists.

Comment: it looks like you don't have package.json in every service?

Comment: In every service there is a package.json file i have added screen shots of the folder in the question .The nginx service does not have a package.json file but I don't think it needs one .

Comment: Can you `docker-compose up` without volume?

Comment: Can you provide dockerfiles? I guess you missed some steps in local

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214876/discussion-between-rammusxu-and-deepesh-acharya).

Comment: Of course without volume It works, same as me! The problem still because you have to put It on c/Users/yourusers because of special permissione, not only in Users. That's a volume issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error! Actually I solved moving my project to /c/Users/currentUser from c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox. Maybe you have your project folder inside Program Files directory and not inside Users one, is It right? Try with this, Just Copy your project folder inside users and running your docker-compose from there. Let me know!

Comment: Tried it but it is not working i tried running it in user/currentuser as well as in user folder but still it gives the same error exited with code 254 in all three services that use volumes.

Comment: Are you sure? We are doing the same course, same section and same error. Did you move in that folder in terminal using CD? Show me your terminal

Comment: I've seen you screenshot. You posted your project in Users, you have to Place It on Users/yourUser !!